# Is it possible to change the Azure AD that an Azure SQL instance authenticates against?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

When we create an Azure SQL server, we can opt to have it authenticate users against Azure AD, but I don't see any option during creation (or afterward in the settings pages of the server instance) to select which directory, if the account has more than one; it seems to just use the one marked as "default" in the directories list. The account I'm creating the SQL server in has 4 directories, two normal and two B2C:

[image: Sample Image1]

The "setup a new SQL server" wizard offers "Azure AD" as an option, but not any choice of which:

[image: Sample Image2]

How do we change the directory a particular SQL server uses? And can it be an Azure AD B2C directory, or does it have to be an Azure AD type directory?

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but my gut feeling is that it is not possible. SQL automatically uses the AAD linked to the subscription as far as I know.

Comment: Perhaps my approach has been wrong, then, in terms of auth for the web app; the website uses one of the B2C directories to auth its users, but its connection string for the DB has been Active Directory Interactive, which auths against the other directory. It seems to have become a bit of a muddle..

Comment: It would certainly be simpler if the app back-end used an account of its own (or a Managed Identity). Though if you want per-user authorization at DB level, that won't help for that.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely **set the directory of the Azure SQL server that you are connecting to by specifying the ‘Azure subscription context’ and the Azure subscription and tenant details as shown below in the ‘Connect-AzAccount’ cmdlet and then connecting to the correct Azure SQL database through the SQL Server Management Studio**. As **`when through the powershell, you connect to the Azure subscription account by specifying the correct details in the context of your Azure tenant and subscription, the device based login is done successfully and when you connect through the SSMS, the SQL servers and databases are shown that are created in the specified tenant`**.

Thus, in this way, **you can connect to the Azure SQL Database server with the configured Azure AD authentication. Also, please do take note that when you are provisioning an Azure SQL server, it asks you an option to select the ‘Azure AD Admin’ for that SQL server as below in which you can select the user (default) that needs to be used an SQL Administrator for the deployed Azure SQL DB Server**.

[image: Powershell connect]
[image: SQL Server connect]
[image: Database connection]
[image: Azure AD admin selection]

•   *`Therefore, in this way, you can select the Azure AD tenant from which you want to authenticate to the SQL server. Also, please remember that each subscription can only trust a single directory/Azure AD instance, whereas multiple subscriptions can trust the same Azure AD instance. As a result, in the same Azure AD tenant, you can associate multiple subscriptions but the vice versa is not possible. Hence, please check accordingly`*.

Please check the below given link for more details: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory***